# VSCode merge conflict don't show code conflict but other git gui tools show?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

There is a conflict when I merge a branch: `git merge main`.

I want to use main branch changes directly.

when I use VSCode resolve conflict (main branch is on the left, my branch is on the right):

[image]

I click "Accept All changes from left" button:

[image]

Line 16 of result is my branch!

---

But I use other git GUI(IDEA, sublime merge, etc) show (main branch is on right, my branch is on left):

[image: sublime merge]

I click "taker right" button:

[image]

Line 16 of result is main branch!

Why?

VSCode Version:

[image]

Comment: Both of these tools seem to indicate the same thing... am I missing something?

Comment: line 16 , VSCode don't show conflict

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean.  Both of these tools are showing the same thing, except they are visually different.  These are basically 3 way file comparisons being shown.

Comment: I re-describe it as best I can

Answer (score 0):

do you using a same merge.conflictstyle?
if u do so, the result must be the same,

u can try this,

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

and do it again in ur command line

```
git merge xxx
```